# ObjC / C++ same code with different error

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode

I have two files in the same Xcode iOS app project:

- first one is .m (type Objective-C Source)

```
    void test(void **param)
    {
        
    }
    
    void start ()
    {
        void *param = NULL;
        test(param);
    }
```

- second is .cpp (type C++ Source) with the same code

```
    void test(void **param)
    {
        
    }
    
    void start ()
    {
        void *param = NULL;
        test(param);
    }
```

The first one compiles and runs without any issue but the second gives an error during compile time that there is `"No matching function for call to 'test'"` and I need to use an explicit cast to match the function param.

What is the difference between the two of those? Does Obj-C not check types for void params or is doing it automatically?

Comment: A `void*` argument is not a `void**` parameter.

Comment: Unlike C++, Objective-C is a superset of C. C++ has a stricter type system than C.

Comment: the error suggests there is no declaration for `void test(void **param);` aka header file. 
`.cpp` in Xcode would need `.hpp` header or you go for both with a `.h` header file. If there is no matching header file you will very likely directly include the cpp but that does not mean its functions are available outside the scope of declarations where you included it. If your goal is to mix cpp with ObjC you will want to read more about `.h`, `.hh` + `.mm` files and their effect, working with ObjC++ then.

Comment: and sorry @molbdnilo C++ does not have a stricter type system but it has overloading. Aka classes carry their class footprint with them while in C mostly everything relies on pointers without the need of class informations.